# Install UWP application on SD card

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

I'm creating a `UWP` application for my **Raspberry Pi 3, Model B** - running **Windows 10 IoT Core**. I want to know how to install it on my SD card, I have not been able to find any documentation for this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much exploration and discovery, I found that you can connect to the **Raspberry Pi** via its IP address when it is connected to your network. In a browser enter the IP address in the URL, this will prompt you for credentials credentials -- there are defaults for the "Administrator" account. Once you're in you can manage the file system make deployed apps the default startup app (which essentially is like installing them).